# Flash/FLEX 3 Argument Error 2082

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Has anyone else experienced this error? Sometimes it pops up at the beginning of loading the application with Argument Error 2082. The only way I can solve it is by rebooting my machine. Restarting the browser doesn't even solve it. I have read about some solutions on the web, but I am interested in knowing what others have tried using that solved the error for them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in Flash, there's a pretty long discussion about it here:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/63829

The long and short of it is you should wrap your localConnection.connect() in a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the [Actionscript 3.0 Runtime Error 2082](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/runtimeErrors.html)?